# Javascript: replace min files with regular files

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I downloaded this d3 JavaScript project from GitHub https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries, and then I created an HTML page (index.html) to run the project.
This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./d3_timeseries.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3_timeseries.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/create-example-data.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script>
    var data = createRandomData(80,[0,1000],0.01)
    var chart = d3_timeseries()
                  .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
                  .width(820)
    chart('#chart')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want replace the two min files with the regular files, 
that is, I want to replace `d3_timeseries.min.css` with `d3_timeseries.css` and `d3_timeseries.min.js` with `d3_timeseries.js` but there are problems. Infact there are two errors:
[image]

Comment: You should probably raise an issue in the Github repo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue in your source file, it's working well for me. Moreover I checked the source code and it seems fine too. Here is a snippet which works :

```js
var data = createRandomData(80,[0,1000],0.01);
var chart = d3_timeseries()
            .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
            .width(820)
chart('#chart')
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries/a5bab438/dist/d3_timeseries.min.css">

<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries/a5bab438/dist/d3_timeseries.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/create-example-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wanted to say that I replace this line: '<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3_timeseries.min.js"></script>' with this: '<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3_timeseries.js"></script>' I have this two errors